# firefox android addon incompatible when submit to AMO

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I recently develop an addon for Android Firefox, I only used the compatible modules according to [Module_Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development#Module_Compatibility), I package my addon using [jpm-mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm-mobile). When I submit it to AMO, it just said

> Some platforms are not available for this type of add-on.

And in Validation Results page, it says no compatibility.
[image]

So how can I tell which api is incompatible ? Is there any way to check this out ?

BTW, I tried cfx with following command:

```
cfx run -a fennec-on-device -b `which adb` --force-mobile
```

And it succeeded installing  my addon to firefox.

FYI, [this](https://github.com/jiacai2050/gooreplacer/tree/android) is my addon codes.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that message. It is only saying htis message because in your `install.rdf` you did not put the key for firefox for desktop, you only put the key for firefox for android. The validator is not testing compatibility of any APIs.